# Forward any mail sent to any of my domains on my server to my single gmail email

Tags: ubuntu, email, forwarding, postfix

I've got an ubuntu server and a bunch of domains on it e.g.:

- domain1.com
- domain2.com
- domain3.com

And I want to be able to forward any emails sent to any of those domains to my single gmail email.

e.g.

```
tips@mydomain1.com => me@gmail.com

foo@mydomain2.com => me@gmail.com

bar@mydomain3.com => me@gmail.com
```

Would this be relatively easy to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to forward mail, you can ask gmail to collect mail from your other email accounts using POP3

https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=21288

> Welcome to our information center for Gmail's Mail Fetcher. Mail Fetcher can download messages from up to five other email accounts, centralizing all your email in Gmail

...

> Once you've set up Mail Fetcher, Google will check your other accounts on a regular basis, and new mail will appear automatically in Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting your mail to these domains currently (if at all)?  The usual solution is a mailserver somewhere that will accept mail to these domains and you tell it to forward anything it gets.  You then advertise your mailserver with MX records at your DNS server.

You can run your own mailserver on your Ubuntu machine or your ISP may provide one (if you're setting up domains, I presume you have a static IP account which usually comes with a mailserver) or you can just buy the service at any hosting company of your choice.  If you use your ISP's or somebody else's commercial mailserver, they'll typically provide a web interface to help you set everything up.

But Googling just now, I notice another new alternative is to use [Gmail to host your email domain](http://smarterware.org/3628/host-your-domain-email-at-gmail-without-forwarding) directly.  I haven't tried it but they apparently will do it for free.